When I try to send an e-mail with Node.js Nodemailer, it says sent but it is not sent
As I mentioned in the title, I am trying to send an e-mail using nodemailer, but although I receive the sent log, I do not receive any e-mails in my mailbox, including the spam folder. What could be the reason? Email being 'sent'

Are you sure you're using the correct options for your SMTP connection? Do you have an available SMTP server running?. Please provide some more details.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@NikkieDev I am trying via ethereal email, everything is correct, even it seems that the ethereal email was sent in the sent emails section of the website, but when I look at my own email address, there is nothing like that, how can I solve this?

@MehmetDaeky . Could it be that you're receiving it in your spam?

Did you set-up DKIM/SPF/DMARC? Please have a look at the section "prevent emails from being flagged as spam" of the following answer

If your DMARC policy is set to 'drop' & your SPF/DKIM are misconfigured, the email won't even hit the junk mail folder. An email that's successfully sent or even received is not necessarily delivered. You should add all relevant e-mail DNS records in your question & SMTP debug logs.
